# .NET: Pass-by-reference is a lie?

Tags: .net, vb.net, pass-by-reference

I encountered an interesting case where pass-by-reference does not appear to work in VB.NET. I've supplied some sample code below for you all to play with. Can anyone explain this phenomenon. Is this intended, or a bug with the language/compiler?

What I am seeing with this code is that the "After Increment" read-out is the same as the "Before Increment" readout.

```
Public Class Wrapper
    Public Property Value As Integer
End Class

Sub Main()

    Dim rand As New Random()

    Dim w As New Wrapper()
    w.Value = rand.Next()
    Console.WriteLine("Before Increment: {0}", w.Value)

    Try
        Increment(w.Value)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Console.WriteLine("After Increment: {0}", w.Value)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Public Sub Increment(ByRef i As Integer)
    i += 1
    Throw New Exception()
End Sub
```

Comment: This is VB code not C#

Comment: Sorry - corrected. I switch between the two often in my work environment. You can easily convert this to C# and see the same result.

Comment: No, you cannot convert this to C# and see the same result because C# has different rules for passing properties as byrefs than VB does.  Try it!

Comment: @iam1me and before you try suggesting Eric Lippert is wrong you might want to check his credentials

Comment: Hmmm, I shall and will let you know if i in fact see something different.

Comment: And anyway, *your* question is tagged C#. So **you** can easily provide the C# version rather than every single person who is looking at C# tagged questions having to do it.

Comment: Actually, I corrected it to  VB.NET tag a while ago. People just started responding instantly as i was correcting it.

Comment: No you didn't (check the version history). You *added* the VB.net tag. Others have removed the tag and reference to C#.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I encountered an interesting case where pass-by-reference does not appear to work in VB.NET.

Indeed, this is quite an interesting case.

> I've supplied some sample code below for you all to play with. Can anyone explain this phenomenon.

Yes.

> Is this intended, or a bug with the language/compiler?

This behaviour is by design and it is not a bug.  **You should not write VB code like this**. If it hurts when you do this, **stop doing it**.

This all makes sense, but you have to understand the logic of it. Follow along

- A byref is an alias to a variable. That is, when you pass a variable to a method that takes a byref, the formal parameter becomes an *alias* for the variable.  We have *one variable* with *two names*.
- A property is not a variable. A property is a pair of methods: a getter and a setter. A property may be *backed* by a variable, but a property is not a *variable*. It is a getter that *produces a value* and a setter which *receives a value*.  Make sure you are clear on the difference between values and variables. Variables contain values.
- What then happens if you attempt to pass a property to a method expecting a byref parameter?  In C#, that's illegal.  **In VB, the compiler generates a temporary variable for you and passes it by ref using copy-in-copy-out semantics**.  That is, your program is equivalent to:

---

```
Try
    Dim Temp As Integer
    Temp = w.Value  ' copy-in
    Increment(Temp) ' make an alias to Temp
    w.Value = Temp  ' copy-out
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

---

Now it should be obvious why your program has the behaviour that it does. **The throw happens before the copy-out**.

---

People often say that C# and VB are "the same language" with different syntax, and there is some truth to that. However, examples that show small differences illustrate that the languages have different design principles. It is not an accident that C# and VB differ in their treatment of values passed by ref!

Design principles of C# include that the compiler should tell you when the code looks wrong and in particular the compiler should not "paper over" problems by guessing what you meant, and emitting code to kinda-sorta make it work most of the time. The design team sees the attitude of C# programmers as "the compiler is my friend who tells me when I'm wrong so I can improve".

Design principles of VB include that the code probably works just fine, and that if there's something that looks not quite right, figure out what the user meant and make it work, even if that means introducing code that, say, doesn't preserve object identity, or adds a hidden copy-in-copy-out or whatever. The design teams sees the attitude of VB programmers as "the compiler too often stands in my way; I've expressed an intention so make it work".

Both design principles are entirely sensible and there are large developer constituencies for each. I think it is quite nice that Microsoft has spent decades doubling the expense of language development so that developers have the ability to choose a language that suits their temperaments.

That said: there are situations in C# where the compiler will do something similar: create a temporary variable, assign a value to it, and then pass the variable by ref.

**Challenge:** create a program which demonstrates this fact.

**Hint #1:** mutable structs are a bad practice in C# for a reason.

**Hint #2:** under what circumstances is a variable treated as a value in C#?

Comment: `w.Value = Temp` should maybe be removed? meaning I don't think that represents OP's code, according to your description, since `Temp` is being updated and `w.Value` was not.

Comment: @cwharris: I'm not following your point. VB implements copy-in-copy-out. You are suggesting that I remove the copy-out. Why?

Comment: @cwharris: Read the original code more carefully.  The copy-out is never reached because the method throws, transferring control to the catch and skipping the copy-out.

Comment: Good answer, Thank you @EricLippert.

Comment: @ParrishHusband: I'm not following your train of thought; can you explain why you think this shows a temporary variable being created?  (It does not; what's happening here is every time through the loop a *new variable called b* is created. Remember, `for(...n times...) { int b = blah(); }` should logically be the same as `int b1 = blah(); int b2 = blah(); int b3 = blah(); ... int bn = blah();`

Comment: @EricLippert I thought ExchangeAdd was doing that, but thinking about this more that makes zero sense, so I'm having trouble with my own train of thought here.  Will think this through, and look at the generated IL closer.

Comment: @ParrishHusband: We effectively have `ref this.i` in the call to `Interlocked.Increment`, and since `this` is already a ref to `Incrementable`, there's no problem making a ref to its only member. Since refs are of course actually implemented as managed pointers, there's no problem here; the ref to `this` and the ref to `this.i` will be the same pointer.